# Element only shows sometimes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menubar for my website with `home`, `about`, and `contact` links. They are aligned on the right side of the page. For some reason, when I reload the page, sometimes contact seems to return to the next line. I don't have to change anything for this to happen. 
Here is the relevant css:

```
ul#menubar {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Cantarell";
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

li.menubar_item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5%;

}

li.menubar_item a {
    color: #D2F2FE;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menubar_div {
    height: 150px;
    padding-right: 5%;
 }
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul id="menubar">
    <li class="menubar_item">
        <a href="index.html"><div class="menubar_div">Home</div></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menubar_item">
        <a href="#about"><div class="menubar_div">About</div></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menubar_item">
        <a href="#"><div class="menubar_div">Contact</div></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your `padding-right: 5%` that ruins it. Since you haven't set a width for the `ul#menubar`, it's automatically set to 100%. The problem is that the width expands with the padding, causing it to be a total of 115% (100 + 5x3).

You can add this to your ul#menubar:

```
width: 85%; 
text-align: right;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line in your CSS :

```
ul#menubar {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

The property `white-space:nowrap` force the `li` elements to be side by side